# How to make the excel sheet download or set process.env.HOME environment in render?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a workbook saved and I am updating information according to the data available. I am able to make changes on the workbook but I am unable to download it.
or how can we set `process.env.HOME === C:/Users/${Username}.???`
please find the code below:

```
//invoice.jsx
import Wrapper from '../assets/wrappers/DashboardFormPage';
import { FormRow, FormRowSelect, SubmitBtn } from '../components';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import customFetch from '../../utils/customFetch.js';
import { useLoaderData, Form, redirect, useActionData } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CUSTOMER_CODE } from '../../../utils/constants.js';

export const loader = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await customFetch.get('/users/admin/app-stats');
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error('You are not authorized to view this page');
    return redirect('/dashboard');
  }
};

export const action = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const data = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  // console.log(data);
  try {
    await customFetch.post('/users/admin/invoice', data);
    toast.success('Invoice Downloaded');
    return redirect('/dashboard/invoice');
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error(error?.response?.data?.msg);
    return error;
  }
};

const Invoice = () => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Form className="form" method="post">
        <h4 className="form-title">Generate Invoice</h4>
        <div className="form-center">
          <FormRow
            type="text"
            labelText="Invoice Number"
            name="invoiceNumber"
          />
          <FormRow type="date" labelText="Start Date" name="startDate" />
          <FormRow type="date" labelText="End Date" name="endDate" />
          <FormRowSelect
            labelText="Customer Code"
            name="customer"
            list={Object.values(CUSTOMER_CODE)}
          />
          <SubmitBtn formBtn />
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
export default Invoice;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//userController.js

export const downloadInvoice = async (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body;
  const startDateObject = data.startDate === '' ? '' : new Date(data.startDate);
  const endDateObject = data.endDate === '' ? '' : new Date(data.endDate);
  if (data.invoiceNumber === '') {
    res
      .status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
      .json({ msg: 'Please provide Invoice Number' });
  } else if (data.invoiceNumber.length < 10) {
    res.status(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).json({ msg: 'Incorrect Invoice Number' });
  } else {
    const agr = data.invoiceNumber.slice(-4);
    try {
      switch (data.customer) {
        //ASP INVOICE CREATION
        case 'ASP':
          if (startDateObject === '' || endDateObject === '') {
            res
              .status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST)
              .json({ msg: 'Please fill both dates' });
            return;
          } else {
            const graphicOrAspire = data.invoiceNumber[3];
            let aspTripData = [];
            if (graphicOrAspire === 'M') {
              aspTripData = await Trip.find({
                customer: data.customer,
                tripDate: {
                  $gte: startDateObject,
                  $lte: endDateObject,
                },
                oceanLine: OCEAN_LINE.DRYVAN,
                loadCode: {
                  $ne: LOAD_CODE.ASPGRAPHIC,
                },
              });
            } else if (graphicOrAspire === 'G') {
              aspTripData = await Trip.find({
                customer: data.customer,
                tripDate: {
                  $gte: startDateObject,
                  $lte: endDateObject,
                },
                oceanLine: OCEAN_LINE.DRYVAN,
                loadCode: LOAD_CODE.ASPGRAPHIC,
              });
            }
            const totalTrips = aspTripData.length;
            if (totalTrips === 0) {
              res
                .status(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND)
                .json({ msg: 'No trips found between given date range.' });
            } else {
              ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
              await workbook.xlsx.readFile(
                path.join(__dirname, '../public/aspTemplate.xlsx')
              );

              // Get the first worksheet
              const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Sheet1');

              // Add data to specific cells
              //invoice number
              worksheet.getCell('I1').value = data.invoiceNumber;

              //invoice date
              const currentDate = new Date();
              worksheet.getCell('I2').value = currentDate.toLocaleDateString();

              //week number
              const d = new Date(startDateObject);
              d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
              d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - ((d.getDay() + 6) % 6)); // Make the adjustment more dynamic
              const yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
              const weekNumber = Math.ceil(
                ((d - yearStart) / 86400000 + 1) / 7
              );

              worksheet.getCell('H9').value = `WEEK ${weekNumber}`;

              //from
              worksheet.getCell('D16').value = startDateObject;

              //to
              worksheet.getCell('E16').value = endDateObject;

              //Total trips
              worksheet.getCell('G16').value = totalTrips;

              //rate
              worksheet.getCell('H16').value = ASP_CHARGES.ASPWHOUT_BASE_AMOUNT;

//I HAVE ISSUE HERE!!!!!!
              const outputFilePath = path.join(
                process.env.HOME || process.env.USERPROFILE,
                'Invoices',
                'ASP',
                `${data.invoiceNumber}.xlsx`
              );
              console.log(`1: ${process.env.HOME}`);
              console.log(`2: ${process.env.USERPROFILE}`);
              console.log(`PATH: ${outputFilePath}`);
              await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(outputFilePath);
              //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// I AM ABLE TO SAVE CHANGES WHEN I RUN IT LOCALLY, BUT AFTER DEPLOYING IT... I NEED TO DOWNLOAD THIS FILE.
//PLEASE SUGGEST HOW CAN I DOWNLOAD THIS FILE ON BROWSER.

              res
                .status(StatusCodes.OK)
                .json({ aspTripData, msg: 'Aspire Invoice Downloaded' });
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).json({ msg: 'Something went wrong' });
    }
  }
};
```

I tried using XLSX... by creating a new workbook and then trying to download it... but unfortunately unable to do so.